# How to add an incremental suffix to a list of files

Tags: python, windows-10

I am looking for a way to take a list of files that could be called anything, rename the file to match the name of the folder the file is within and increment a suffix.

e.g.

```
 Folder
  |
  |
  |---> File.ext
  |---> File.ext
  |---> File.ext
```

and the result of the script would be:

```
Folder
  |
  |
  |---> Folder01.ext
  |---> Folder02.ext
  |---> Folder03.ext
```

I've got the code to rename the files the same as the parent-folder (see below) however i'm unsure where and how to include the code to increment the suffix.

```py
def walkDir(rootDir):

    for thisDir, thisDir_subDirs, thisDir_files in os.walk(rootDir):

        for filename in thisDir_files:

            basename = ntpath.basename(filename)
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)  
            newname = ntpath.split(thisDir)[1]
            newfilename = ''.join([newname, ext])
            src = os.path.join(thisDir, filename)
            dst = os.path.join(thisDir, newfilename)   
            os.rename(src, dst)

        for rootDir in thisDir_subDirs:
            walkDir(rootDir)
```

Answer (score 1):

enumerate is usually good for this.  You can use the counter i generated by enumerate inside your ''.join() and use zfill to pad it with a zero

```
for i, filename in enumerate(thisDir_files):

            basename = ntpath.basename(filename)
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)  
            newname = ntpath.split(thisDir)[1]
            newfilename = ''.join([newname, str(i).zfill(2),ext])
            src = os.path.join(thisDir, filename)
            dst = os.path.join(thisDir, newfilename)   
            os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Chris, however I need the suffix to increment like:

01
02
03

not

1 2 3

Comment: does the zfill not do that for you?

Comment: Sorry completely missed the text above the code, that does the padding but I'm getting it to the left of the suffix, i'm struggling to get zfill to append to the right of the suffix but before the enumeration.

Comment: I have found a way using _ljust_

suffix.ljust(len(suffix) + 1, '0')

the enumeration needs to be added to the end of the above